# Magento Filter By Relative Value

Tags: magento

I would like to filter a collection by relative value per that row. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_1 > column_2
```

The only thing I know how to do in Magento would be

```
$q = Mage::getModel('table')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToFilter('column_1', array('gt' => $some_number));
```

or something of that sort. I can only give it a value to compare against, not a column name. I also looked at the `Zend_Db_Select` method at the `where` clause but didn't find anything that would help. Do I actually have to go all the way down to a direct SQL query (something which is, of course, avoided at all costs)? (I'm running Magento 1.3.2.4)

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific. I'd say it heavily depends on about what specific kind of collection you are talking about (e.g. 'catalog/product', 'sales/order', self-made). Collections can be of very different types (usage of flat and/or EAV, using joins or not, etc.). What collection is causing the problem at hand? Are the columns you try to compare default Mage fields or custom added? Or a custom table?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
$q = Mage::getModel('table')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('column_1')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('column_2')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('column_1', array('gt' => Zend_Db_Expr('`column_2`')));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is probably not the ideal solution, but it's one way of getting what you need.

This is how I got a collection of products that were on sale, where a products final price is lower than its price.

I first made a new empty data collection. Then defined the collection I was going to loop through filtering what I could first. After that I looped through that collection and any products that matched my requirements got added to the empty collection.

```
    $this->_itemCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

    $i=0;
    foreach($collection as $product){
        if($product->getFinalPrice() > $product->getPrice() && !$this->_itemCollection->getItemById($product->getId())){    
            $this->_itemCollection->addItem($product);
            $i++;
        }

        if($i==$this->getProductsCount()){
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->setProductCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for a way to do the `if($product->getFinalPrice() > $product->getPrice()` in the query not in PHP for performance reasons.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'd love a solution to this!